# Check constraint for string with a format in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, format, check-constraint

I have a table which is defined like:

```
create table HLV (
id nvarchar(7) check (id LIKE 'HLV[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]') Primary key,
birthday date,
full_name nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
win int check (win > 0),
lose int check (lose > 0),
draw int check (draw > 0)
)
```

I execute the code and it works, but when I insert the data into it with

`insert into HLV values ('HLV0001',GETDATE(), 10,5,6)`

I got the error

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Is it because the check is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is because you missed `full_name` in your insert statement:

```
insert into HLV values ('HLV0001',GETDATE(), 'michael jordan' ,10,5,6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand of Giorgi Nakeuri's Answer,

When you use `insert into HLV` without any column names, sql server assumes you are going to pass all the columns defined in the table (except for columns like `identity`). In your `Insert` query

```
insert into HLV values (N'HLV0001',GETDATE(), 10,5,6)
```

SQL Server is expecting values for all the columns `id, birthday,full_name,win,lose,draw`
However you are only passing values for `id, birthday,win,lose,draw`, hence the number of values provided does not match the table definition.

If you column `full_name` allowed `NULL` values or had a `DEFAULT` constraint, you could do something like this

```
insert into HLV(id, birthday,win,lose,draw) values (N'HLV0001',GETDATE(), 10,5,6)
```

Additionally based on your check constraint on `ID`, you should change it's type from `nvarchar(7)` to `CHAR(7)`.

Answer (score 1):

There are 6 columns in the table, but only 5 values in the insert statement values clause. You can fix the problem by specifying all 6 required values, however I would also strongly recommend to specify the column names in the insert statement to make it more robust to change, more self-documenting. You won't have to be sure of the actual column order. You can omit nullable and defaulted columns. New nullable or defaulted columns can be added without breaking the statement.

```
ALTER TABLE HLV ADD gender char(1) NULL

INSERT HLV (id, birthday, full_name, win, lose, draw)
VALUES ('HLV0001', GETDATE(), 'first last', 10, 5, 6)

INSERT HLV (full_name, id, birthday)
VALUES ('last, first', 'HLV0002', GETDATE())
```

There are loads of examples on [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776381%28v=sql.105%29.aspx#BasicSyntax).