# Add Check Constraint to Version number column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to figure out how to add a `CHECK` constraint to the `Version` column to only accept `NVARCHAR` values with the format as such for example:

```
(Number.number.number)
10.4.1
```

or

```
(number.number.number. 3numbers)
10.4.1.111
```

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table
(
    ID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    Version NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL CHECK (Version)
)
```

Desired result would be, when a users updates the `Version` column, they must adhere to the defined formats.

For example, `11.3.4` would be acceptable and `12.4.3.444` would be acceptable.

Comment: I haven't been able to find anything, and I can't think of the logic on this myself or if it's even possible. So I'm just looking for some humble ideas.

Comment: You would be better off doing the validation in the application layer; hopefully one that supports Regex. SQL Server has no such support for Regex.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29959218/check-constraint-for-string-with-a-format-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
USE tempdb;
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo._tbl;

CREATE TABLE dbo._tbl (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, ver VARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO dbo._tbl (ver) VALUES
('10.4.1'),
('10.4.1.111');

alter table dbo._tbl
add constraint codeCheck check (COALESCE(TRY_CAST(PARSENAME(ver, 1) AS INT) 
    + TRY_CAST(PARSENAME(ver, 2) AS INT) 
    + TRY_CAST(PARSENAME(ver, 3) AS INT), 0) + COALESCE(TRY_CAST(PARSENAME(ver, 1) AS INT)
    + TRY_CAST(PARSENAME(ver, 2) AS INT) 
    + TRY_CAST(PARSENAME(ver, 3) AS INT) 
     + TRY_CAST(PARSENAME(ver, 4) AS INT), 0) > 0);

-- it will fail
INSERT INTO dbo._tbl (ver) VALUES
('10.4.r');

-- it will work
INSERT INTO dbo._tbl (ver) VALUES
('17.7.77');

SELECT * FROM dbo._tbl;
```